# how to build search bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i m a beginner in flutter and i need help. The goal is to have a search bar in order to find users with their name.
i call users with provider and their data with the AppUserData model class

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:models/user.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FilterLocalListPageState createState() => FilterLocalListPageState();
}

class FilterLocalListPageState extends State<UserList> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<AppUserData>>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("users"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: users.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return buildBook(users[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBook(AppUserData user) => ListTile(
        leading: Image.network(
          user.profilepic,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        ),
        title: Text(user.name),
      );
}
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SearchDelegate`, check out this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Wm3OiFBZ2xI).

it's a little bit boring, but it gets the job done.